# When using "opposite to", is a corresponding word necessary?

Tags: prepositions

[image]

Which sentence is grammatically correct to invite friends to my house? In particular, I want to know whether "exit" after "opposite to" is necessary.

> 1. When coming to my house by train, please get off at ABC station and
>          use an exit opposite to the stadium.
> 2. When coming to my house by
>          train, please get off at ABC station and use an exit opposite to
>          **an exit** that is located closer to the stadium.

Comment: Your second example is unnecessarily complex. That's really not such a good idea in *any* circumstances - but it would be particularly unfortunate if your friends aren't native Anglophones (I am, but I still had to read the second example twice before realising that it was just an extended version of the first). FWIW, I suspect many people might find it easier to follow if you said *...and use **one of the exits** opposite the stadium.*

Comment: "opposite *from* the stadium".